Do these verses mean humans can see multiple heavens
I was looking at these verses and wondered if humans are able to view multiple heavens. I know that the stars in the sky that we see are really far away and they are in the lowest heaven and wonder what else it is we can see
Quran 10:101

"Say, "Observe what is in the heavens and the earth." But of no avail will be signs or warners to a people who do not believe."

Quran 7:185

"Do they not look into the realm of the heavens and the earth and everything that Allāh has created and [think] that perhaps their appointed time has come near? So in what statement [i.e., message] hereafter will they believe?"


In both of these ayats Allah didn't said Earths. In both of them Allah refers to a single Earth and multiple heavens or skyes. Allah also didn't said 7 heavens. So, clearly Allah is not referring to the 7 heavens and Earths. As, I said earlier Allah refers to a single Earth. So we can conclude that from " single Earth and multiple heavens" that Allah is referring to the layers of our sky. Because it is a good sign for disbelievers that how Allah classified different elements in different layers.
